# c# how to detect image color

Tags: c#, image-processing, colors

I have a picture and in my picture there are several drops of blood of different colors. I want to get the color of each drop of blood (either by color name, or by color code)
[image]

Comment: So, what have you tried? What tasks did you identify so far? Hint: Each drop consistes of several quite different hues..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use this to get each Pixel Color in image

```
using System.Drawing;


Bitmap b = new Bitmap( "Image file Path" );
Color x = b.GetPixel( x, y );
```